# Reading a specific txt file and re-arrange it to a given format

Tags: string

Below is an output of Chemichal analysis instrument. I need to rearrange the format and sort it in a way that percentage figure for each element goes below its name. My question is how to read this file word by word? how can I choose, for instance word number 12?

txt file format:

Header_1    Date     Time       Method_Name (Filter_Name)       Calc_Mode       Heat No.                        Quality                         Anal. Code                      Sample ID                           C               Si              Mn              P               S               Cr              Mo              Ni              Al              Co              Cu              Nb              Ti              V               W               Pb              Sn              As              Bi              Ca              Sb              Se              B               Zn              N               Fe          Place Code                      Work Phase

## Single      13.01.13 09:51:10   Fe-10 Test                      AutoResult      12A                                                                                                                                 00001.040       00000.437       00000.292       00000.023       00000.007       00001.505       00000.263       00000.081       00000.012       00000.014       00000.110       00000.155       00000.040       00000.098       00000.015       00000.014       00000.013       00000.012       00000.002       00000.001       00000.016       00000.014       00000.005       00000.001       00000.016       00095.813

Comment: Do you realize you are asking someone to not only do ALL of the work for you, but (apparently) choose the language and platform to do it in?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a good knowledge of programming and while searching here, I taught someone could be helpful by giving me a hint. I need to know how to read n-th character in my file. Having known this, I will try to finalise the code myself.

Comment: I am looking for help in C++  by the way!

Answer (score 0):

To find word 12, read the line character by character until you have seen 11 instances of whatever is being used to separate words (which you have not specified); what follows, until the next such separator, will be the 12th word.